# Cannot connect to server using some applications

Tags: networking, ssh, connection

I've been using ssh to connect to my server for weeks, but 24h ago it suddenly stopped working. The following things I tried:

1. When I enable VPN on my local machine I *can* connect
2. When using my phone's hotspot, I can also connect
3. I can also connect from my other server

Thus, the server is up and accepts ssh connections.

1. I can ping the server successfully from my local machine without VPN,
2. I have tried connecting after running `ufw disable` on the server, but still no luck.
3. `fail2ban` is not installed

When trying to connect from my laptop I get

```
ssh: connect to host xxxxxxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

The attempt to login does not even make it into the auth.log file.

Using wireshark I see that when trying to connect my packets result in [Conversation completeness: Incomplete, SYN_SENT (1)].

At this point I'm not sure what could be causing this?

edit:
traceroute to the ip does not terminate, but does leave my home network. Is it possible that some router along the way for some reason started blocking my requests?

Comment: Share more details about the issue like error output when you are trying to ssh to the server from client end or server ssh logs in /var/log/auth.log file.

Comment: @ShivamAhuja added

Comment: Since you don't see any SSH connection attempt in the auth.log, it's worth checking if you can detect a listener on port 22 at all. Can you reach the server with `nc -z x.x.x.x 22`? If this does not succeed, the packets are being dropped by firewall.

Comment: @jbielick I tried traceroute to see where my traffic is going, and it seems that it does not get past one of the nodes (it does leave my own network, so I have no local firewalls that cause the issue). Do you know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: Did you try `nc`?

Comment: @jbielick Yes, it says "nc: connectx to xxxx port 22 (tcp) failed: Operation timed out"

Answer (score 0):

First thing as you have mentioned is that SSH service is up and accepting new connection so most likely nothing is wrong on server side of this situation.

So the problem is from client side ( again most likely ) and since when you connect to VPN or use mobile data you can connect, there should be something wrong with you ISP network.

my advice is first check things on your side for example check if you mistakenly blocked some connections on your router modem ( check firewall of your router and NAT settings ). finally if everything sees fine check with your ISP support they might be able to help.

Comment: I tried traceroute to see where my traffic is going, and it seems that it does not get past one of the nodes (it does leave my own network, so I have no local firewalls that cause the issue). Do you know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: can't say for certain but if i were you i would share this problem with ISP and ask if they can help or check their side, Again Im not saying its the problem of ISP 100 percent but they have better view of traffic and might help